# How to add connection string reference in master page code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to reference a connection string set up in my web.config file using a master.cs file that is supposed to supply this value for my regular aspx.cs file. When I reference the connection string variable that is set in the master page's cs file, my regular .cs page or code behind page doesn't recognize it in intellisense. I'm a little of a newbie, so there's a small misunderstanding that I have about how master page code behind files interact with the aspx and cs files that it is a master for. Note, I am using the AHAH method rather than AJAX where there is no xml or json as the recipient of the get request, and instead it returns html

**addBusiness.aspx**

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="worker.master.cs" Inherits="worker" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**addBusiness.aspx.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class addBusiness : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Request["firstName"] != null && Request["lastName"] != null && Request["fullBusinessName"] != null && Request["displayName"] != null && Request["fullAddress"] != null && Request["phone"] != null && Request["email"] != null && Request["password"] != null && Request["streetAddress"] != null && Request["city"] != null && Request["state"] != null && Request["zip"] != null && Request["lat"] != null && Request["lng"] != null)
        {
           //this is where I am trying to reference the connection string from worker.master
            con.open();
        }
    }
}
```

**worker.master.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

public partial class worker : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ViewEta"].ConnectionString);
    }
}
```

**worker.master**

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="worker.master.cs" Inherits="worker" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This may not solve your problem - but I would strongly recommend not creating a connection when you load the master page.  The connection should be created when you need it, and disposed of right after it's done.  Web pages should not be interacting directly with the database, either, but that's a different argument.

Comment: This is a good point.  If you are going to do it this way, I highly recommend you implement the IDisposable interface on your masterpage and dispose of the connection in the IDisposable.Dispose method

Comment: Both these pages are setup as MasterPages. `addBusiness.aspx` has the same page directive and HTML as `worker.master`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a property on the System.Web.UI.Page class that contains a reference to the master page named Master.

In order to share the connection created in the master page you are going to have to store it somewhere the Web Page can find it.  This is usually done in a property, e.g.

```
public partial class worker : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
    public IDbConnection Con {get; private set;}

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Con = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ViewEta"].ConnectionString);
    }
}
```

Then in your web page, use the Master property to get the master page.  There's a cast to your specific type in order to access the property on your Master

```
public partial class addBusiness : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Request["firstName"] != null && Request["lastName"] != null && Request["fullBusinessName"] != null && Request["displayName"] != null && Request["fullAddress"] != null && Request["phone"] != null && Request["email"] != null && Request["password"] != null && Request["streetAddress"] != null && Request["city"] != null && Request["state"] != null && Request["zip"] != null && Request["lat"] != null && Request["lng"] != null)
        {
           worker masterPage = this.Master as worker;
           masterPage.Con.open();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In his example code the `addBusiness.aspx` page has `CodeFile="worker.master.cs"` in the Page directive. I don't see where `class addBusiness` gets used

Comment: Nice catch.  There are some additional stylistic and resource problems with this code.  Hopefully this answers the OP's question and if they have additional problems they'll post additional questions

Comment: Yes I am assuming it is a copy and paste error on the OP's part.

Comment: It's not. It's bad code form someone who has never had to do this

Comment: although all answers seem to be correct, I'm going to mark the one directly above as the most comprensive and therefore most correct, but it looks like if I have to do this, it'[s just as easy to put the connection string on the regular.cs file and not even bother with a master.cs file.

Answer (score 1):

You have declared the

```
SqlConnection con
```

variable inside the page_load function. So the variable not accessible outside the master page's page_load method. Even within the master page itself.

Declare the variable outside the method with public/protected access modifier and access them like this,

```
((MyMasterPage)this.Master).con;
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

please make sure you are you are Adding properly liberary to the master page 
please check this Thanks.